# How to get the current view name from layout template in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to get the name of the currently rendered view from inside layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something like this for css namespacing:

```
# config/initializers/action_view.rb
ActionView::TemplateRenderer.class_eval do

  def render_template_with_tracking(template, layout_name = nil, locals = {})
    # with this gsub, we convert a file path /folder1/folder2/subfolder/filename.html.erb to subfolder-filename
    @view.instance_variable_set(:@_rendered_template, template.inspect.gsub(/(\..*)/, '').split('/')[-2..-1].join('-'))
    out = render_template_without_tracking(template, layout_name, locals)
    @view.instance_variable_set(:@_rendered_template, nil)
    return out
  end

  alias_method_chain :render_template, :tracking
end


# application.html.erb
<body class="<%= :@_rendered_template %>" >
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `<% __FILE__ %>` to get the complete file path of current view, but you can only use it from *within* the file itself without writing some helpers

Answer (score 3):

The method active_template_virtual_path method returns the template as a name in the following form "controller/action"

```
 class ActionController::Base
  attr_accessor :active_template

  def active_template_virtual_path
    self.active_template.virtual_path if self.active_template
  end
end

class ActionView::TemplateRenderer 

  alias_method :_render_template_original, :render_template

  def render_template(template, layout_name = nil, locals = {})

    @view.controller.active_template = template if @view.controller
    result = _render_template_original( template, layout_name, locals)
    @view.controller.active_template = nil if @view.controller
    return result

  end
end
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I am trying to `<%= controller.active_template %>` in template. It says `undefined method `active_template'`

Comment: <% __FILE__ %> will give you name of current template

Comment: This says: "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::FILE"

Comment: This would do:  <%= __FILE__ %>

Comment: it is `__FILE__`, not `FILE`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question. I found `<%= params[:controller] %>` and `<%= params[:action] %>` to suit my need, which was to add the controller name and action name as classes on the body tag.

Just in case that helps anyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using a modified version of Peter Ehrlich's solution. The resulting string is of the form `controller_name/view_name`, e.g. `users/new`, which means it can be passed directly to `render` later on, or altered to suit other uses. I've only tried this with Rails 4.2, though as far as I know it ought to work all the way back into the 3.*x*es.

```
ActionView::Base.class_eval do
  attr_accessor :current_template
end

ActionView::TemplateRenderer.class_eval do
  def render_template_with_current_template_accessor(template, layout_name = nil, locals = {})
    @view.current_template = template.try(:virtual_path)
    render_template_without_current_template_accessor(template, layout_name, locals)
  end

  alias_method_chain :render_template, :current_template_accessor
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purpose, you can use gem 'current_template' from [here](https://github.com/shihokambara/current_template).

This gem inspects logfile and display file name of view/partial template.

For example:

[image]

Also, you can simply add this line

`` <%= "#{`tail log/development.log`}".scan(/\s[a-z]+\/\S+/) %> ``

to your layout/application.html.erb.